# Ruby block variable scope within/out the method

Tags: ruby, variables, block

I get the following different results:

Test 1:

```
def myblock
  x = 1
  y = 1
  yield(x)
  [x, y]
end

myblock do |x|
 y = 10
end
# => [1,1]
```

Test 2:

```
x = 1
y = 1

1.upto(2) do |x|
  y = 20
end
[x,y]
# => [1,20]
```

Variables created outside the block are available in the block. Why are they so?

Comment: “Why are they so?”—because blocks in ruby are closures.

Comment: but why the 2rd block can change 'y'？

Answer (score 2):

That is how the scope of a local variable is defined. A local variable can percolate into a block, but not into a method definition.

Comment: Technically there is another issue; in the first snippet there are no local variables crossing boundaries of the method definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myblock
  x = 1
  y = 1
  z = yield(x)
  puts "y=#{y}, z=#{z}"
  [x, y]
end

myblock do |x|
 y = 10
end
y=1, z=10
  #=> [1, 1]
```

This shows that three things are going on here:

- The `y` in the block is unrelated to the `y` in `myblock`. That's because the scope of the `y` in the block is confined to the block. Ruby can only get her hands on what is returned by the block, not on what's going on inside of it.
- The block does indeed return the value of `y` in the block, but only because `y = 10` was the last statement executed in the block. The execution of that statement returns `10`, so `10` is returned by the block. Had the block contained `y = 10; 7`, `7` would have been returned.
- The value of `yield(x)` is not captured by the variable `y` in `myblock`, so it has no effect.<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 It's a little-known fact that Ruby actually shoots such values into outer space.</sup>

Comment: that makes sense for test1, but how about test2？it seems "Ruby knows what's going on inside the block", So y is changed to 20. am I right？ thankyou

Comment: In Test 2, it is because `y` is  defined before the block that `y` in the  block is the same `y`. If you remove `y = 1` and you run the code (try it) you

Comment: It is because `y` is initialized before the block that it is the same `y` inside the block. Remove `y = 1` and `[x,y]` will raise an exception: "Name error: undefined local variable 'y'". It has to be that way for the block to be able to use previously-defined variables in the block calculations. Here `y = 1.upto(2) { |x| 20 }` would work (but it doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 0):

After more testing and searching:

For Test1, x and y is method level local variable and they don't share the scope with block. y in the block is a new local variable(block level).

For Test2, x and y is class level local variable and they share the scope with block, y in the block is still the outside y(class level).

It's all because I messed up the scope, thanks all.